# W3C HTML5 Validation Issues

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

HTML WITH ERRORS

```
<meta description="keywords" content="Quekett, restaurant, Pub, Isle of Wight, Fresh, Lobster, Crab, Seafood, Bembridge, Food, Dining, Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Bed and Breakfast, B&amp;B">



<link href="CSS/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)">
```

[image: W3C Validation Issues]

Just attempted to validate a HTML5 site I'm building and have cleared out the majority of the issues but stuck with these 4 lingering issues below any ideas on what possible fixes to get rid of these?

Comment: It'd be helpful if we could read the issues. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: You can open the image in a new window to see it full size, but we still can't see the code causing these issues...

Comment: I believe the line of code with the issue is displayed below each error ? I can provide the whole HTML document but its quite large and I think all the information is provided ?

Comment: @HenryQuekett: Not all of it.

Comment: The two lines of HTML flagged up with issues have been posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning 1:**

> "Attribute description not allowed on element meta at this point"

means, that you are not allowed to have an attribute called `description`. Examples of valid meta-tags can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Your tag would then look like:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Quekett, restaurant, Pub, Isle of Wight, Fresh, Lobster, Crab, Seafood, Bembridge, Food, Dining, Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Bed and Breakfast, B&B">
```

**The second Warning** is a consequence of warning 1, you can ignore that if you have fixed number 1.

**Warning 3:** I don't understand what exactly you want there, so I give you the w3c recommodations on media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

**Warning 4:**
You have a reserved HTML Entity in your text/link. You have to escape that. Escaping in HTML means that you escape ith with the charactes `&`, followed by a code, and ending with `;`. So `&` gets escaped to `&amp;` since the code for the ampersand is *amp*.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

There is an interesting Blog about the usefullness of 100% valid HTML
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/html-validation-does-it-matter.html

Comment: Do this even though its a web address link wont that lead to a 404 error and the script not being found ?

Comment: No, because browsers parse that symbol correct. Actually I don't know why you shouldn't be allowed to use `&` directly, but if you insist to have 100% valid HTML code, don't use it anymore. It works both.

Answer (score 0):

To validate your HTML5 site use [Validator.nu](http://html5.validator.nu/). A good IDE with HTML5 support is NetBeans and Aptana.